# Multiple Calculated Fields Using Linkable Behavior Not Working

Tags: cakephp, behavior, cakephp-2.2

I'm in my ArticlesController trying to display a list of the top article posters sorted by their number of articles DESC. The table also needs to display the total number of points a user has (no order). When I calculate either the total number of articles or the sum of points by itself, it works fine but it returns the incorrect values of each when I try to calculate both number simultaneously. For example, if  a user has 5 records in the articles table and 10 records in the points table (for a sum of let's say 50 points, 5 points each), then it will output that the user has 50 articles, and 250 points.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'User.username', 'User.online',
    ),
    'conditions'    => array(
        'Article.page_id'  => $page_id,
        'Article.status_id BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(2,6),
        'Point.page_id'  => $page_id,
    ),
    'link'  => array(
        'Article' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Article.id', 'COUNT(Article.id) AS articles'
            )
       ),
       'Point' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Point.id', 'SUM(Point.amount) AS page_points'
             )
        ),
    ),
    'group' => 'User.id',
    'order' => 'articles DESC, User.username ASC',
    'limit' => 35,
    'contain' => array(
        'Avatar' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Avatar.file'
             )
        ),
    ) // contain
);

$this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue still stands with multiple calculated fields using the Linkable behavior results in the calculations being skewed. The numbers that are returned are multiplied by the number of rows of each other linked model.

Below actually accomplishes what I want but even better because it works with pagination sorting.

```
$this->User->virtualFields['page_points'] = "(select SUM(amount)
    from points as Point 
    where Point.user_id = User.id
    AND Point.page_id = $page_id
)";

$this->User->virtualFields['page_articles'] = "(select COUNT(Post.id)
    from posts as Post
    where Post.user_id = User.id
    AND Post.page_id = $page_id
    AND Post.status_id BETWEEN 2 AND 6
    AND Post.module_id = $module_id
)";

$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'User.id', 'User.username', 'User.online', 'User.points', 'User.page_points', 'User.page_articles'
    ),
    'link'  => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Post.id'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'group' => 'User.id',
    'order' => 'User.page_articles DESC, User.username ASC',
    'limit' => 10,
    'contain' => array(
        'Avatar' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Avatar.file'
            ) // avatar fields
        ), // avatar
    ) // contain
); // paginate

$this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));
```

Apparently if I don't still link to the Post model it doesn't work. So I link to the Post model and just obtain one id. Query speed does not seem to be an issue. I can't COUNT the posts within the linkable or else I won't be able to use the result in the paginator sort.